# Create UIView with custom shape

Tags: ios, uiview

So I was wondering if there's a way to make a UIView with a custom shape.

I'm trying to make a piano keyboard so when the user touches the view a delegate method responds by playing a noise. The picture is a .png with the picture of the key and a transparent background.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a `UIView` in the shape of, say, a triangle, but what you *can* do is make the view transparent, then add your non-transparent content to it.

**For example**, to make a view with a background of a png (with, I assume, partially transparent areas) you could make a transparent `UIView` and then add an image view to it. **better yet**, just use a `UIImageView` in the place.

Comment: ... and you can override `-pointInside:withEvent:` if you want custom geometry for touch detection.